# Array select to get true and false arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I know I can get this easily:

```
array = [45, 89, 23, 11, 102, 95]
lower_than_50 = array.select{ |n| n<50}
greater_than_50 = array.select{ |n| !n<50}
```

But is there a method (or an elegant manner) to get this by only running `select` once?

```
[lower_than_50, greater_than_50] = array.split_boolean{ |n| n<50}
```

Comment: You are looking for [Array#partition](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
over, under_or_equal = [45, 89, 23, 11, 102, 95].partition{|x| x>50 }
```

Or simply:

```
result = array.partition{|x| x>50 }
p result #=> [[89, 102, 95], [45, 23, 11]]
```

if you rather want the result as one array with two sub-arrays.

Edit: As a bonus, here is how you would to it if you have more than two alternatives and want to split the numbers:

```
my_custom_grouping = -> x do
  case x
    when 1..50   then :small
    when 51..100 then :large
    else              :unclassified
  end
end

p [-1,2,40,70,120].group_by(&my_custom_grouping) #=> {:unclassified=>[-1, 120], :small=>[2, 40], :large=>[70]}
```

Comment: Ruby is so beautiful! :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is spot on!

Here is a general solution for more than two partitions (for example: `<20, <50, >=50`):

```
arr = [45, 89, 23, 11, 102, 95]
arr.group_by { |i| i < 20 ? 'a' : i < 50 ? 'b' : 'c' }.sort.map(&:last)
=> [[11], [45, 23], [89, 102, 95]]
```

This can be very useful if you're grouping by chunks (or any mathematically computable index such as modulo):

```
arr.group_by { |i| i / 50 }.sort.map(&:last)
=> [[45, 23, 11], [89, 95], [102]]
```